# How to remove js scripts from the new, empty MVC project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I created a new empty MVC project in VS2015 and as soon as I added my first view I got a lot of js scripts that I didn't add. I see them in the developer tools but not in the solution. What are they and how do I remove them?
Here are some of them:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://localhost:49298/87aa8b8ac2e54745b6c572fb65172bf0/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->
<script src="//dmp.adriverssp.com/scripts/stat/adriverssp.js?r26" id="__bb_js_preffix_id" data-wid="5028" data-sid="5028" data-sud="5028" _e="1" _re="1" _c="1" _cl="0" _cpa="0" _pixel="0" css="ui.css" js="ui.js" async="" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//trendtext.eu/37d2b1bb945e0c3753.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trendtext.eu/metric/?mid=&amp;wid=49544&amp;sid=&amp;tid=893&amp;rid=LOADED&amp;jsonp=window.__twb__37d2b1bb945e0c3753.reportSetCallback&amp;custom1=localhost:49206&amp;t=1453837765845"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trendtext.eu/metric/?mid=&amp;wid=49544&amp;sid=&amp;tid=893&amp;rid=BEFORE_OPTOUT_REQ&amp;jsonp=window.__twb__37d2b1bb945e0c3753.reportSetCallback&amp;t=1453837765845"></script>         
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trendtext.eu/optout/get?jsonp=__twb_cb_512368056&amp;key=37d2b1bb945e0c3753&amp;t=1453837765846"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trendtext.eu/metric/?mid=&amp;wid=49544&amp;sid=&amp;tid=893&amp;rid=FINISHED&amp;jsonp=window.__twb__37d2b1bb945e0c3753.reportSetCallback&amp;custom1=localhost:49206&amp;t=1453837765846"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trendtext.eu/metric/?mid=&amp;wid=49544&amp;sid=&amp;tid=893&amp;rid=OPTOUT_RESPONSE_OK&amp;jsonp=window.__twb__37d2b1bb945e0c3753.reportSetCallback&amp;t=1453837765905"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trendtext.eu/metric/?mid=lnkr&amp;wid=49544&amp;sid=&amp;tid=893&amp;rid=MNTZ_INJECT&amp;jsonp=window.__twb__37d2b1bb945e0c3753.reportSetCallback&amp;t=1453837765906"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trendtext.eu/addons/lnkr15.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trendtext.eu/metric/?mid=lnkr&amp;wid=49544&amp;sid=&amp;tid=893&amp;rid=MNTZ_LOADED&amp;jsonp=window.__twb__37d2b1bb945e0c3753.reportSetCallback&amp;t=1453837765910"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some sort of Malware installed in your browser or on your machine.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'll take a look

Comment: I cleared the malware and all scripts are gone. Thank you, I spent hours trying to figure out what's the mAtter

Comment: Neat malware! I've never come across anything that's infected Visual Studio before.

Comment: For other people that may be searching for "lnkr15.min.js"/trendtext.eu , I had this introduced to the DOM by a Chrome responsive preview extension.

Answer (score 2):

I found that there are several browser extensions that insert calls to this (and other) domains, the calls are potentially malicious and could do a variety of things including monitoring all your browser traffic, but also steal your passwords, credit card data and other personal information.

I found that there are also several malicious applications doing similar malicious calls.

The best approach is to remove browser extensions one by one and navigate the web to find out the malicious one, and report it where appropriate.

Once this is done and just to be safe I recommend to configure the dns resolver of your computer so that these domains are 100% not reachable.

add the following two lines:

```
127.0.0.1       cr-input.mxpnl.net
127.0.0.1       trendtext.eu
```

to the hosts file of your computer:

- for unix: `/etc/hosts`
- for mac: `/private/etc/hosts`
- for windows: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

only with this you can be certain that you are not accessing the malicious domains.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem with chrome. To make sure where the problem is,

1. I checked the same page in firefox and ie. These browsers had no such problem. then it was sure that this problem is chrome specific.
2. Updated chrome to the latest one. Problem still was there.
3. I disabled then enabled extensions. Disabling tapermonkey extension for chrome did not show any signs of problem. Then it was sure that it was causing trouble.
4. Then removing it completely solved problem for ever.